# Feature contribution interview question I can't answer

Tags: interaction, feature-engineering, importance

A few weeks ago, I had an interview for a data science job. Of all the questions they asked me, I was unable to solve the following one. I couldn't even attempt it because I didn't know anything about it. I have researched, but I can't find any book, paper, blog, etc. that shows the question.

So here's what I remember from the question:

The following table has the "feature contribution" of feature i with observation j. Additionally, each feature is divided into different categories. Category 1 has features 1, 2, and 3, Category 2 has features 4 and 5, and Category 3 has only feature 6.

| Observation | F1/C1 | F2/C 1 | F3/C1 | F4/C2 | F5/C2 | F6/C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -4 | 4 | 1 | 2 | -2 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | -1 | 0 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 | -3 |
| 5 | -3 | -2 | 0 | -2 | 2 | 1 |

If I recall correctly, they asked me to obtain the feature importance of each category. So the expected result was three numbers, one for each category.

During the interview, I attempted to calculate the means and sums and then means again, but the answer was never correct. Do any of you have any references on how to solve this problem?

Comment: This seems like a terrible interview question to me, for several reasons.  Sorry you had to put up with it.

Comment: @jbowman That’s the part where the potential employee is interviewing the firm, too!

Comment: As a lowly one rep person, I can't comment but agree with jbowman and the comments. It seems needlessly complicated. It's like they were trying to test some weird combo of feature selection and dimensionality reduction together in some algebra manipulation task. If you're ever confused on interview questions, some of the best feedback I ever got was to ask them questions back. Sometimes companies ask these questions to test if you'd push back on confusing or vague questions. Sorry for non-answer answer. Just restudy PCA and tree models and a good company will be more than willing to hire you.

Comment: @jbowman the correct concept is feature attribution and not contribution. Will correct later. So even if my question is not 100% correctly stated do you stand by your judgement?

Comment: Don't be afraid to ask questions, especially when you don't understand.  You might get positive reactions to questions for clarification, such as "could you elaborate on what you mean by "feature contribution" and "feature importance"?  You might even make progress by asking broader questions, such as "what is the objective" or "what kind of model do you have in mind"?  The interviewer could be trying to identify potential employees who *don't* view all problems as if they are textbook exercises ;-).